# Accessing Sharepoint 2007 via Adobe Air App using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, air

I need to Check out, Edit, and Check in documents on a Sharepoint 2007 server. The documents are XML format. I want to do this in an Adobe Air application which is all HTML and Javascript. I have tried `XMLHttpRequest()` with no luck. At this point I am just trying to read the file.

Is there a way to do this via client-side script?

This is what I have tried:

```
function testGet(url){
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type','text/xml; charset=utf-8');
     xmlhttp.send();
     if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
         xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
         alert(xmlDoc);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got SharePoint 2010 you can use the JavaScript (EMCAScript) version of the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535231.aspx) to manipulate documents.

This shows using the Managed Client Object Model (the .net version) but you should be able to do the same using the JavaScript version - [Using the SharePoint Foundation 2010 Managed Client Object Model with the Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524.aspx)

If you're using SharePoint 2007 then you can use the [SharePoint web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28v=office.12%29.aspx) - this codeplex project should give you a start using the web services from javascript - [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It looks like the latter should work, SPServices, but I'm having difficulty with implementation. The problem is I have permissions to the SP site but not direct access to the server. The code will be running client-side, on the same domain as the SP server. This should work right? There's not many working examples I could find..

Comment: Yes that should work - the web services don't require that the code is running on the server and if running client side will use your login credentials. The web services can be disabled though and best to use a web service testing tool like SoapUI to ensure they are working and help test your code.